# How to get event info from an event link?

Tags: python-2.7, caldav

I would like to use CalDAV python module to get the whole information from an event, I managed to get a link for the event, but I do not understand how to get the event detail from that event, so I have the link to the event:

```
https://mail.example.com:443/public-calendars/example.com/9A0F7585-A952-4E0C-868C-0C072A2D8740/9a0f7585-a952-4e0c-868c-0c072a2d8740-0000048a.eml
```

And I am trying this to get the event details:

```
event = 'https://mail.example.com:443/public-calendars/example.com/9A0F7585-A952-4E0C-868C-0C072A2D8740/9a0f7585-a952-4e0c-868c-0c072a2d8740-0000048a.eml'
eventDetail = caldav.Event(event).load()
```

But I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'request'
```

What I would like to get is something like this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:event-title
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Warsaw:20150305T130000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Warsaw:20150305T140000
DTSTAMP:20150624T170317Z
UID:9149F870-5475-4120-9EE5-1A06E857807B
SEQUENCE:1
EXDATE;TZID=Europe/Warsaw:20150618T130000
EXDATE;TZID=Europe/Warsaw:20150305T130000
EXDATE;TZID=Europe/Warsaw:20150430T130000
CREATED:20150226T105018Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20150616T094907Z
LOCATION:
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20150624T235959Z;INTERVAL=1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:NONE
TRIGGER;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19760401T005545Z
UID:FC67F59E-5540-47BE-ACFA-FE229771EC11
X-WR-ALARMUID:FC67F59E-5540-47BE-ACFA-FE229771EC11
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
```

I would like to put that into a variable, so that I can go through that information and search for what I need or send it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the modules [caldav/objects.py](https://bitbucket.org/cyrilrbt/caldav/src/40cfd242774e5d9db51c3deeb10bad85d47f81d7/caldav/objects.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#objects.py-683)
I see:

```
def __init__(self, client=None, url=None, data=None, parent=None, id=None)
```

You are passing in the URL as the client object (1st parameter), hence the error.

Maybe this would work, but probably not (to load, it quite likely needs a client object):

```
eventDetail = caldav.Event(url=event).load()
```

But looking further down the module I see an [`event_by_url`](https://bitbucket.org/cyrilrbt/caldav/src/40cfd242774e5d9db51c3deeb10bad85d47f81d7/caldav/objects.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#objects.py-581) on the calendar object:

```
class Calendar(DAVObject):
  ...
  def event_by_url(self, href, data=None):
```

Presumably you already have access to the calendar objects, so I suppose it may be a simple:

```
event = calendar.event_by_url("/calendars/123.ics")
```

Comment: I found out that this will basically print the specific event:

Comment: print event.data

Then you can use different objects on event, like for example name:

print event.name

Answer (score 0):

Take the event url and try something like:

```
event_url = 'https://mail.example.com:443/public-calendars/example.com/9A0F7585-A952-4E0C-868C-0C072A2D8740/9a0f7585-a952-4e0c-868c-0c072a2d8740-0000048a.eml'
eventl = calendar.event_by_url(event_url)
```

Then you can load data into an object "<class 'vobject.icalendar.RecurringComponent'>" like this:

```
event_data = eventl.vobject_instance.vevent
```

And, for example, access "SUMMARY" like this:

```
event_summary = eventl.vobject_instance.vevent.summary.value
```